# List of all default application programmatically

Tags: android

How can I get a list of Default applications in Android devices programmatically?

For example, in my phone there may be two Video player.

1. Samsung Video player
2. VLC.

But it is quite possible that VLC is set as default player.
Like this, I want to find programatically all the Default applications.
I have been able to get list of Installed applications and Launcher applications but how could I find list of all default applications.

Comment: Not duplicate brother. Here I just want to know which apps are set as default. For example, in my phone there may be 2 Video player. 1. Samsung Video player 2. VLC. But May be VLC is set as default player in my OS. Like this, I want to find programatically all the Default application. Not installed or launchable application. @Torcellite

Comment: Please add that detail to the question. It's unclear otherwise.

Comment: Done. I think the question is now more precise. Sorry for being vague first time.

Comment: I believe you are aware that the user can change the default application.When several application can handle a particular Intent a chooser dialog is presented to the user by the OS and user can choose the default application to handle that Intent.

Comment: Is there any way to do this programatically? Or there does not exist any way of doing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getPreferredActivities()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPreferredActivities%28java.util.List%3Candroid.content.IntentFilter%3E,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.content.ComponentName%3E,%20java.lang.String%29) like this:

```
    List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
    List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    getPackageManager().getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);
```

This will put all default activities in the list called `activities`.